# How to solve error "export 'MaskDirective' (imported as 'i3') was not found in ngx-mask" for Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ngx-mask

While building the angular app on azure devops pipeline getting an error related to ngx-mask. But on local it is working fine.

The error is:-

```
./node_modules/cdp-angular-controls/fesm2020/cdp-angular-controls.mjs:1964:67-83 - Error: export 'MaskDirective' (imported as 'i3') was not found in 'ngx-mask' (possible exports: INITIAL_CONFIG, NEW_CONFIG, NGX_MASK_CONFIG, NgxMaskDirective, NgxMaskModule, NgxMaskPipe, NgxMaskService, _configFactory, initialConfig, timeMasks, withoutValidation)
```

I'm using ngx-mask 14.2.4.
[image]

Initially I upgraded the ngx-mask version from 14.2.3 to 14.3.0 but was getting

```
"Error: src/app/app.module.ts:18:10 - error TS2305: Module '"ngx-mask"' has no exported member 'NgxMaskModule'.
18 import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask';"
```

So, I downgrade it to 14.2.4 and it was working fine.
But, after code check-in to server while running the pipeline getting new error.

Expectation:-
-> Build is successful on local & devops pipeline.
-> OR get the same errors on server & local.

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is with just this error message, can you please provide more details? By the way, if you are using Microsoft hosted agent, maybe you can try using self-hosted agent and see if it works. If it works, compare the difference between self-hosted agent and Microsoft hosted agent.  To see more detailed logs, you can add a variable named system.debug and set its value to true.